# How to add jQuery on Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I'm trying to use some jQuery on my website. I tried to use the code from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348666/add-jquery-in-yii-2-0)

and i can't find my error. I tried to put he code on layot/main.php and on site/index.php and no result. Here is my simple jQuery Code:

```
 <select name="dropdown" size=1>
<option value="1">option 1</option>
<option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>

<?php
use yii\web\View;
$this->registerJs(' $("select[name="dropdown"]").change(function(){

if ($(this).val() == "2")
    alert("call the do something function on option 2");

});', View::POS_READY);
?>
```

Please Help!!

--- EDIT ---
It work on this way:

```
<?php
use yii\web\View;
$this->registerJs("
$('select[name="."dropdown"."]').change(function(){
$("."'#teste'".").html('call the do something function on option '+$(this).val());
if ($(this).val() == '2')
    alert('call the do something function on option 2');

 });", View::POS_READY);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mistake with quotes in your JS :

```
"select[name="dropdown"]"
```

Change it to

```
$this->registerJs(' $(\'select[name="dropdown"]\').change(function(){

if ($(this).val() == "2")
    alert("call the do something function on option 2");

});', View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Got the solution on diferent way. You can check on my edit. Can you explain me what the "\" does?

Comment: backslash escapes quote, so it became part of string instead of closing first quote mark.

Comment: how I can change the jquery.js file position in yii2? by default it is in footer.